# How restart weblogic server after Authentication error

Tags: weblogic

I am trying to restart my weblogic server (Weblogic Server Version: 10.3.5). It throws the below error. I used to restart is regularly earlier but it is throwing this error today.

I have replaced the boot.properties file with the correct username and password and on trying to restart, I see that it is getting encrypted, but the server is not starting up. I have also tried modifying the config.xml and entered the decrypted password, but still I get the error.

```
Starting WLS with line:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/bin/java    -server -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Dweblogic.Name=ManagedServer -Djava.security.policy=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/cacerts   -da -Dplatform.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3 -Dwls.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server -Dweblogic.home=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server   -Dweblogic.management.discover=false -Dweblogic.management.server=http://kbzuatapp:7001  -Dwlw.iterativeDev=false -Dwlw.testConsole=false -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole=false -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=/u01/Oracle/Middleware/patch_wls1035/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath:/u01/Oracle/Middleware/patch_ocp360/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom  weblogic.Server
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:35 PM MMT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true> 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:36 PM MMT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true> 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:36 PM MMT> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Version 19.0-b09 from Sun Microsystems Inc.> 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:37 PM MMT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090065> <Getting boot identity from user.> 
Enter username to boot WebLogic server:Error: Failed to get value from Standard Input
Enter password to boot WebLogic server:
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:37 PM MMT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 10.3.5.0  Fri Apr 1 20:20:06 PDT 2011 1398638 > 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:38 PM MMT> <Error> <Configuration Management> <BEA-150021> <The admin server failed to authenticate the identity of the user  starting the managed server. The reason for the error is .> 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:38 PM MMT> <Emergency> <Management> <BEA-141151> <The admin server could not be reached at http://kbzuatapp:7001.> 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:38 PM MMT> <Info> <Configuration Management> <BEA-150018> <This server is being started in managed server independence mode in the absence of the admin server.> 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:38 PM MMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING> 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:38 PM MMT> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool> 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:38 PM MMT> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/KBZUAT/servers/ManagedServer/logs/ManagedServer.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms like Windows.> 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:38 PM MMT> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/KBZUAT/servers/ManagedServer/logs/ManagedServer.log00011. Log messages will continue to be logged in /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/KBZUAT/servers/ManagedServer/logs/ManagedServer.log.> 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:38 PM MMT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file /u01/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/KBZUAT/servers/ManagedServer/logs/ManagedServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.> 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:41 PM MMT> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.> 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:41 PM MMT> <Critical> <Security> <BEA-090403> <Authentication for user  denied> 
<Oct 19, 2012 8:01:41 PM MMT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user  denied
weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user  denied
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:965)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1050)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
    at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090304]Authentication Failed: User  javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: [Security:090301]Password Not Supplied
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.login(LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:261)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper$1.run(LoginModuleWrapper.java:110)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper.login(LoginModuleWrapper.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why it is trying to get boot identity from the user when I have provided the details in boot.properties. Btw, I don't get any prompt for username and password on the screen.

Comment: you will not get prompt for user name and password if boot.properties is there at $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/security/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got the solution. I deleted the edit.lok file and then tried the restart. It worked.

Comment: didn't solve my problem but you DID give me another thing to look for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As for me, I had to edit the file `boot.properties` and set there AGAIN the login and password for the weblogic server. The previous values were encrypted and obviously, some SW couldn't manage it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the `ManagedServerDir/data/ldap` directory.

do not forget to backup

Comment: I have tried deleting ManagedServerDir/data/ldap directory and it worked but whats the permanent solution for it I am trying to spin-up lot of nodes and don't want to delete ldap directory in all servers

Answer (score 0):

Just do a root level search for boot.properties & edit.lok in the weblogic server and delete them. (take the back up before deleting it) and restart the server.

It works :-)

---

---

---

Answer (score 0):

I have solved in this way:

- Under **{domain}\servers\AdminServer\data\ldap** delete just files on the root and not the ones inside ldapfiles
- Remove username - passwrod from boot.properties file under **{domain}\servers\AdminServer\security**

After the restart, it asks me the credentails and it works as expected.